# Laravel Log Exception

Tags: laravel

Is there any way i can convert laravel log string to Exception Object.

> [2018-06-17 12:19:34] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: proFirmDarta\Firm' in G:\xampp\htdocs\firm\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:365
>   Stack trace:
>   G:\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php(365): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined index...', 'G:\xampp\htdocs...', 365, Array)

I took this string from laravel log file. 
i want to convert each log to object so i can get message as

```
$e->getMessage();
```

Comment: did you use `try ...catch` ?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [ARCANEDEV/LogViewer](https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/LogViewer). It's a package that makes log's readable. You could reverse engineer their package to see how they read the logs. Especially his [LogParser](https://github.com/ARCANEDEV/LogViewer/blob/master/src/Helpers/LogParser.php)